# Need help using index on a string in python

Tags: python, indexing

When I try to use indexing to get the last element of my line, it does not work( prints out a blank line). However, when I print the original line it works.

```
with open( newFile,"w") as f: 

    f.write("Model Number One" + "\n")
    for l in lines:
        if "ATOM" in l : 
            f.write(l[-1]) #Does NOT work, prints empty line
            f.write(l) # Prints the whole linem when I only want the last element of the line
```

[When index is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27nlF.png)
[When index is not used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMM1s.png)

Comment: What's `lines`?  Is it a list of strings or a list of lists of strings?

Comment: It is a list of strings!

Comment: If `lines` is a list of strings, then each `l` in `lines` is a string, and each index is a single character.  To split it into a list of whitespace-separated words you want `split()`.

Answer (score 2):

The cause might be that the line has a new line character at the end. If the last element of the line is a "\n" since the file has multiple lines, then it will definitely print a blank line.

Comment: I figured that might be, so I tried f.write[-2], f.write[-3], and etc, but it printed numbers from 0 to 9. I knew this was wrong because the last column starts at 1 and ends at 41.

Answer (score 2):

Each line is a string, and so each index is a single character, with the last one being a linebreak (`'\n'`).  If you want to get whitespace-separated substrings out of that line, use `strip` to remove the linebreak, and `split` to split the resulting string on whitespace:

```
with open( newFile, "w") as f: 
    f.write("Model Number One" + "\n")
    for l in lines:
        elems = l.strip().split()
        if "ATOM" in elems: 
            f.write(elems[-1] + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kengru mentioned, there could be a newline at the end. To test try f.write(l[-2]) instead of f.write(l[-1]).

Comment: I figured that might be, so I tried f.write[-2], f.write[-3], and etc, but it printed numbers from 0 to 9. I knew this was wrong because the last column starts at 1 and ends at 41

Comment: If possible, copy paste the last line of that file you're trying to read.